# How can we use airflow-code-editor or simple-dag-editor on AWS airflow MWAA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

The plugins "airflow-code-editor" or "simple-dag-editor"  are designed to edit dag directly in airflow interface.

Sadly they don't work on MWAA because of a "Read-only file system" error.

Is there a way to make them work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Airflow Code Editor version >= 7.0.0 you can show/edit files on S3.

You have to:

- create the file "requirements.txt" in the dag bucket with the following content:

```
airflow-code-editor
black
fs-s3fs
```

- in the Amazon MWAA console "DAG code in Amazon S3" section set
  "Requirements file - optional" to the path of the requirement.txt file
- in the "Airflow configuration options - optional" section, add an option and set "Configuration option" to **code_editor.mount** and
  "Custom value" to **name=dags,path=s3://your_bucket** (replacing "your_bucket" with the name of your S3 DAGS bucket).
- in IAM console, edit the Airflow's IAM role and add permission for writing and deleting objects from the bucket

```
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject*",
                "s3:PutObject*",
                "s3:DeleteObject*",
                "s3:GetBucket*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::your_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::your_bucket/*"
            ]
        },
```

- wait until Airflow is upgraded (minutes)
- in the Airflow tree, now you have a new node "dags" under "Files", you can read/write dags from this folder.

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks a lot for you answer ! 
I tried it right away but it didnt work I have "Error saving order_test.py: operation failed, [Errno 30] Read-only file system: b'/usr/local/airflow/dags/order_test.py'" when I save

Comment: I have fs-s3fs airflow-code-editor>=7.0.0 in my requirements.txt
and code_editor  mount  name=dags,path=s3://my_bucket in AirflowUI/configuration

Comment: are you the author of airflow-code-editor ?

Comment: I saw you edited you message so I tried again but with no success